# jade "include" doesn't work as expected

Tags: scala, pug, scalatra, scalate

Referencing another Jade file from within one:

```
include ../widget
```

Renders HTML like this:

```
<include>../widget</include>
```

Using Scalatra, specifically. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Scalate Jade is different than JavaScript Jade, so the tag isn't the same. You have to reference the filename in full, like so:

```
- include("../widget.jade")
```